# AppEngine default IAM

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine

I made a mistake and removed the default IAM role of an Firebase app on Google Cloud Console.

What is the default IAM role on AppEngine?

Is the `App Engine Admin` the correct one?

[image]

Comment: The default role is Editor

Comment: Thanks you @FerreginaPelona, I think that is the correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written by @Ferregina in the comment section, the default IAM role for App Engine is the [Editor role](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/service-account#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20the%20App%20Engine%20default%20service%20account%20has%20the%20Editor%20role%20in%20the%20project), which means that any user account with
sufficient permissions to deploy changes to the Cloud project can also run code with read/write access to all resources within that project(i.e. User
account having editor role will also be having viewer role or read/write access).